# My computer runs extremely slow after few minutes?

Tags: windows-7

I am runing windows 7 home premium. When I start computer first 10 minutes it runs normally but then it slows down extremely, even when the cpu usage is low.I've tried everything like defragmenting and disk cleaning but it is still slow, what do I do?

Comment: follow this http://pastebin.com/at7DyJxm. Run the command before the slowness occurs, minimize the CMD Window and when you have the issue, restore the cmd and capture 30 -60s of the slowness and then press a key to stop logging.

Comment: Is the slowness coming from CPU activity or disc activity? Is the HDD LED blinking/on? What CPU usage does taskmgr.exe show?

Comment: Could you please post details of your system - CPU, hard drive, RAM, etc

Comment: i have pentium dualcore processor cpu 2.70Ghz.2GB Ram,video card NVIDIA GeForce 8400s of 512Mb and mode 1366 by 768 with 32 bit.and two disk drives C and D.

Comment: TO  Werner Henze:i don know that slowness is coming from CPU activity or disc activity but HDD LED is blinking.And cpu usuage from task manager less than 20.

Comment: i have much more free spaces on both disk drives.and recently i have tried registry cleaning too yet it is slow.

Comment: @AshishAdhikari run the commadn I posted. This traces waits so I can see why Windows is slow.

Comment: Install Process Explorer (available from MS) and see what it reports.  You may have, eg, a "wild" interrupt consuming half the CPU.  Plain old Task Manager misses a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You could be suffering from overheating hardware, which would account for everything running fast the first 10 minutes, especially video cards and CPUs are sensitive to this. If you have a dirty heatsink (plugged full of dust) then that could be a problem. Consider getting a can of air to clear it all out. I know it sounds obvious but I can't count how many times I thought something was wrong with a machine just to find it was overheating... (sometimes unfortunately after an install).

If you you want to separate hardware from software, I suggest running a live operating system and see if the problem persists in the same way. If so, you know your installed OS is fine. I would do these things before making changes to your system.

(PS: i know this is pretty late)

Answer (score 0):

Windows includes two troubleshooting programs that you can use to automatically fix some common problems with your computer's performance or with maintenance of your system.

Open the Performance troubleshooter by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type troubleshooter, and then click Troubleshooting. Under System and Security, click Check for performance issues.

Open the System Maintenance troubleshooter by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type troubleshooter, and then click Troubleshooting. Under System and Security, click Run maintenance tasks.

Comment: i do whatever you said but troubleshooter can't identify the problems in both cases

Comment: Uncheck all the startup applications which are not necessary. Clear your temporary files. Ensure that there is proper free space in system partition.

Answer (score 0):

Run WindowsUpdate and make sure you have all the updates
Make sure your Virus Scanners is Update To Date
Scan your system with Malware Bytes or something like that.

Slow loading applications? Dragging the mouse across the screen? Keyboard input. Battlefield 4 is running slow? =). Please give a little more info.

Comment: yes slow loading application but not mouse and keyboard and also slow games.

Comment: You could try recreating the paging: http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/32471-disable-delete-recreate-paging-file-windows-7-a.html